# One properties configuration file for Multi Apps on Mule ESB runtime

Tags: mule, esb, anypoint-studio

Today I have the same properties configurated on mule-app.properties file for each Apps. Like this:

[image]

All Apps (+ that 5) are running on the same Mule ESB runtime (CE).

For example, when It is necessary to change a host or password, I need to change the properties file of the all apps.

I would like to have just one properties file on Mule ESB runtime shared by all apps.

Is there a form to make this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Mule project and call it "shared". Now, in this project, you can create a file ***`src/main/resources/config.properties`*** and there put all the settings you need.

To have these settings in your current project, just add the project "shared" in the "Projects" tab of the "Java Build Path". Then in the main file of your current project, write

***`< context: property-placeholder location="config.properties" />`***

Comment: In design time works fine! p.e., when Test Connection in Studio. But when it run in Anypoint Studio, occur the following error: `WARN  2016-02-08 17:00:28,088 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [mule-apps.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: Sorry, i forget the classpath. Try 

`<context: property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />`
 
If you get the same, then try with a java project (This is how I have done). Remember to put your properties file in a package (eg `com.company.config`) and use it to reference

`<context: property-placeholder location="classpath:com/company/config/config.properties" />`

Comment: I used Java Project accord your suggestion. But now how I deploy on ESB production this project "shared"? Which path the .properties stay hosted on server?

Comment: When you import your project, the "shared" project is attached as a .jar. You should only change the settings to point to your production servers and ready

Answer (score 1):

Use a Spring Property Placeholder and read a single file from the filesystem:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/path/to/myConfigFile.properties" />
```

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/configuring-properties#properties-files

Comment: I saw this guide, but did not stay clear for me the file localization (path)  on server and the name pattern of the file.

Comment: Updated missing code sample. also depends on your operating system. So unix based: file:/opt/mule/myConfigFile.properties

Comment: Understood! Is there a way to use same relative location to it works both ESB Server and Anypoint Studio?